# YouTube Reporting API returns as 403 when estimatedAdRevenue is included as a metric

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, youtube-api

I am working on a program to do some calculations with ad revenue from YouTube. I have set up OAuth 2.0 through the cloud console and have gotten access and refresh tokens that have the following scopes:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics-monetary.readonly
```

Making this request returns a valid response

`https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/v2/reports?ids=channel==123456789&metrics=views&dimensions=&startDate=1970-01-01&endDate=2050-01-01`

```
{
    "kind": "youtubeAnalytics#resultTable",
    "columnHeaders": [
        {
            "name": "views",
            "columnType": "METRIC",
            "dataType": "INTEGER"
        }
    ],
    "rows": [
        [
            301
        ]
    ]
}
```

However, if I add `estimatedAdRevenue` as a metric using the same authentication, the response is a 403.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Forbidden",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Forbidden",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "forbidden"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Because the query is successfully getting private data (view count), my assumption is that the 403 is because my channel is not monetized, but I can not find that anywhere in the documentation. My end-goal is to get a report of estimated ad revenue per video and I'm pretty sure that getting past this 403 is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was correct - the 403 is caused by not being a YouTube Partner and access to monetization.